# how to calculate difference between two date and get year month and days in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, date-format

**How can I change the Date format in dart**

I get the from and to date difference value is int. How to change this integer to date format... and convert it to 0Days 0Months 7days;
[I need this type of format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JQQn.jpg)

[but I got this type of format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnMry.jpg)
see the Vehicle Age:

```
 vehicleAge(DateTime doPurchase, DateTime doRenewel) {
    age = doPurchase.difference(doRenewel).abs().inDays.toInt();
    return age;
  }
```

That is my function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct Answer**

I got a correct answer [use jiffy package](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy).

`import 'package:jiffy/jiffy.dart';`

then use this code

```
vehicleAge(DateTime doPurchase, DateTime doRenewel) {
    var dt1 = Jiffy(doPurchase);
    var dt2 = Jiffy(doRenewel);

    int years = int.parse("${dt2.diff(dt1, Units.YEAR)}");
    dt1.add(years: years);

    int month = int.parse("${dt2.diff(dt1, Units.MONTH)}");
    dt1.add(months: month);

    var days = dt2.diff(dt1, Units.DAY);

    
    return "$years Years $month Month $days Days";
    
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this package [time_machine](https://pub.dev/packages/time_machine) and try this code

```
 vehicleAge(DateTime doPurchase, DateTime doRenewel) {

  LocalDate a = LocalDate.dateTime(doPurchase);
  LocalDate b = LocalDate.dateTime(doRenewel);
  
  Period diff = b.periodSince(a);
  return "${diff.years} Years ${diff.months} Months ${diff.days} Days";
}
```

Comment: It will give wrong output if you give 361 day

then it will show 0 years 12 month 1 days

Comment: Yes, It is. Updated.

Comment: Also Thank u for ur answer.

Comment: Hello man Your answer is correct but the package ```time_machine``` is not a sound null safety.

Comment: ok. I did not notice about the package.

Comment: You can get a null safe `time_machine` from its master branch ([source](https://github.com/Dana-Ferguson/time_machine/issues/61#issuecomment-853536420)).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 vehicleAge(DateTime doPurchase, DateTime doRenewel) {
    Duration parse = doPurchase.difference(doRenewel).abs();
    return "${parse.inDays~/360} Years ${((parse.inDays%360)~/30)} Month ${(parse.inDays%360)%30} Days";
  }
```

Comment: hello man.... Thanks for Your answer. its working good...

Comment: If ```doPurchase``` and ```doRenewal ``` is same date.  I need the o/p is ```1```day

Comment: Then add another condition with equal and return this.